# Chrome Developer Console question

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to test a feature on my website that produces a random integer. I was wondering if it was possible to use the chrome developer console to trigger a button event with code, without physically pressing the button on the page. Also is it possible to send a different value than what the user put into my textbox. Let's say the user puts his name in "Tom", is there a way to trigger the button event via code in the console as well as change that user input for testing purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run (almost) whatever JavaScript code you want in the console, and it will execute in the context of the page. For instance, to emulate a click on the button, you can type and run:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click()
```

which will click the first button found on the page. You can obviously change whatever value in whatever field this way, but I don't fully understand how you expect to do that - you want to bypass the user, but won't the user be sitting in front of Chrome, whose console you'd like to use?

Comment: Ok what I'm actually doing is the following, I asked the question in context of what I was doing to see if I can figure it out. I'm making a film and I want to use this site [link](http://www.random.org/integers/) to generate the number 95 so I thought I could maybe do this with the console but I haven't a clue how. I wanted to capture the screen go from that page to the random page. This is without editing or cutting the film up. I guess the proper wording is how do I "hack" the site so that eventhough I am generating a number from 1 to 100 it will always return a 95.

Comment: @Tom, Ok... In the results page, if you run `document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0].innerText = "95"` (that will make 95 the only result - you can add more numbers of course, add 95 to the random list or whatever). Now, this will require you to run the command after the page is loaded, which might be a problem in your scenario. If you really want this done, you can have JS loaded into the page before it is shown by writing a dedicated [Chrome Extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).